# Free() function in C does not produce any error on freeing realloced data, but does not free the actual content. What can be the reason?

Tags: c, realloc

So I faced with an issues when I allocate some space, then I reallocate this space inside the recursive function and then I try to free this space outside of recursive function. Free() does not proceed any error, but as debugging shows I still have old content after free() is performed.
Thus I am getting errors like:
1. malloc: *** error for object 0x100200868: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
OR
2.malloc: *** error for object 0x100200000: pointer being freed was not allocated
What can be the reason here?

```
void printTrie(FILE *file, char *initialPath){

    initPath = initialPath;
    if(root.isParent == 0) return;
    char *buffer;
    char *freeCh;
    int *intArr = root.usedIndices;
    int bufferSize = 5;
    int realBufferSize = 0;

    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 36; i++){

        if(intArr[i] == 1){
            buffer = calloc(6, sizeof(char)); //<<<--- have error here after realloc was done inside recursive function
            freeCh = buffer;
            if(i > 9){
                *freeCh = i - 10 + 'a' ;
            }else{
                *freeCh = i + '0';
            }

            freeCh++;
            realBufferSize++;
            recPrint(file, &buffer, realBufferSize, bufferSize, freeCh, &root.children[i]);
            free(buffer); // <<---- try to free content here
        }
    }
}

void recPrint(FILE *file, char **buffer, int realBufferSize, int bufferSize, char *freeCh, NodePtr* temp){

    if(temp -> isParent == 0){ //no superwords in this branch anymore
        temp -> list = getFinalList(temp -> list);
        fprintf(file, "<list> %s\n", *buffer);
        printList(temp -> list, file);
        fprintf(file, "\n<list>\n");
        return;
    }

    if(temp -> isWord){
        temp -> list = getFinalList(temp -> list);
        fprintf(file, "<list> %s\n", *buffer);
        printList(temp -> list, file);
        fprintf(file, "<list>\n");

    }


    int *intArr = temp -> usedIndices;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 36; i++){
        if(intArr[i] == 1){
            if(i > 9){
                *freeCh = i - 10 + 'a' ;
            }else{
                *freeCh = i + '0';
            }
            realBufferSize++;
            if (realBufferSize >= bufferSize){
                *buffer = realloc(*buffer, (bufferSize + 10) * sizeof(char)); //<<--- realloc here
                if(buffer == NULL)
                    printf ("Realloc failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                bufferSize += 10;
            }
            freeCh++;
            recPrint(file, buffer, realBufferSize, bufferSize, freeCh, &temp -> children[i]);

            //now we need to remove all extra characters till the next turn
            freeCh--;
            realBufferSize--;
            *freeCh = '\0';
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `free` doesn't affect the content of freed memory.  It just adds it to the free list of the memory allocator.  Your error message means that you're freeing the storage then using a pointer, which is now invalid because it points to freed storage, to modify that storage anyway.  C gives you lots of rope to hang yourself in this fashion.

Comment: Why do you think `free` failed?

Comment: `if(buffer == NULL)` --> `if(*buffer == NULL)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your program you pass into your program two pointers related to the memory you allocated. One is the address of your `buffer` pointer which you allocated. The other is a pointer into the buffer called `freeCh`.

In your recursive function, you latter reallocate onto `*buffer`. However, a reallocation may return a pointer different from the one that was originally allocated. When this happens, `freeCh` is no longer pointing to a valid memory location. And then, you code modifies the memory at `freeCh`, which is now freed memory.

Incidentally, when `realloc()` returns `NULL`, it has not freed the original pointer that you attempted to reallocate. So, you should not directly overwrite the pointer that you are reallocating with the return value of `realloc()`. You should use a temporary variable, and then test if `realloc()` returned a valid pointer. Assign this value to the pointer you reallocated only if `realloc()` succeeded.